Derivation mean first passage time
When a particle is trapped in a potential $V(x)$, with a reflecting boundary at $x = x_L$ and an absorbing boundary at $x = x_B$, the mean first passage time to reach this absorbing boundary is
$$
\tau_{MFPT} = \frac{1}{D} \int_{x_B}^{x_0} dx e^{\beta V(x)} \int_{x}^{x_L} dx^{'} e^{- \beta V (x^{'})},
$$
with $x_B <= x_0 <= x_L$ and $x_0$ is the starting position. I have seen this equation in the literature, but I cannot find a simple derivation of this? Could anyone provide one or tell me where to find? I would love to understand where it comes from.
Many thanks!

Could you provide an example of where in the literature you have seen this?

In the paper "Effects of static and temporally fluctuating tensions on semiflexible polymer looping" (equation 5), they use this to find the mean first passage time for the ends of a polymer to reach one another.

Eq. 16.3.8 here https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Concepts_in_Biophysical_Chemistry_(Tokmakoff)/04%3A_Transport/16%3A_Targeted_Diffusion/16.03%3A_Mean_First_Passage_Time

@Syrocco The link contains interesting material, however, equation 16.3.8 does not take into account reflection at $x = x_L$.

It might be useful to look at the book by P. Krapivsky and coauthors on nonequilibrium phenomena, where the issues of first passage time are considered, in particular.
Without reading books, the derivation of the formula can be as follows. Considering the presence of $D$ and $V(x)$, we are talking about the diffusion of a Brownian particle in a medium in an external field. As far as I understand, the standard approach is to consider the mean first passage time as a function of the initial position: $\tau(x)$. It is more or less obvious that this function satisfies the following equation
$$
\tau(x) = dt + \overline{\tau(x+dx)},\tag{*}
$$
where $dt > 0 $ is the infinitesimal time, $dx$ is the random displacement from the initial position $x$ over time $dt$ due to diffusion, and $\ \overline{\cdots}\ $ denotes averaging. I think that the following properties of diffusion
$$
\overline{dx} = v(x)dt,\quad\mbox{where}\quad v(x)= -\beta DV'(x),
$$
$$
\overline{(dx)^2} = 2Ddt,\quad \overline{(dx)^n} = o(dt)\quad \forall n>2
$$
are well known. Then, expanding $\tau(x+dx)$ in powers of $dt$ and averaging in (*), we obtain the following differential equation:
$$
D\tau''(x)+v(x)\tau'(x)+1 = 0.\tag{1}
$$
From the formulation of the problem we obtain the boundary conditions
$$
\tau'(x_L) = 0,\quad \tau(x_B) = 0.\tag{2}
$$
The solution of the second-order ODE (1) with boundary conditions (2) is a purely mathematical problem, not a physical one.  However, it is easy to verify that the expression for $\tau_{MFPT}(x_0)$ given in the question  is a solution to this mathematical problem.

Thank you all for the helpful responses. I eventually found the answer in the book: Handbook of Stochastic Methods: for Physics, Chemistry and the Natural Sciences, by Gardiner, Crispin W.. The solution is given on page 139, with an explanation above.
